# how to create a new variable that consists of a sequence based on two other variables?

Tags: dplyr, sequence, data-manipulation

I want to create a variable that reflects women's menstrual cycle day based on information i have regarding their total cycle length and start of their period. I know when their last period started (before the start of the study) and then recorded 35 consecutive days on which women provided whether they started menstruating. the variables i have are: studyday (1-35, same for everyone), cyclelength (varying between persons, calculated based on start last period until start new period), and startmenstruation (i.e. on which study day they indicated their new period started).

in my actual dataset i have 35 datapoints for each ID, and cycle lengths are around 30 days but vary between persons. Just to give you an impression of the type of sequence i am looking to create, I provided a very simplified dataset. So in the simple/short version person 1's cycle length is 5 and the menstruation started on day 2, so day 2 is cycle day 1 for that person, while day 1 was cycle day 5 (the last day of the cycle).
Cycleday (last var) is the variable i want to create with code.

| ID | studyday | startmenstr | cyclength | **cycleday** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 2 |

alternatively, i could use startmenstr as a binary variable with 1 on the study day it started and 0 on other days instead of repeating the study day it started, if that would help.

I have read many posts but did not come across one that uses the info in another variable as the length of the sequence and another one as the starting point, so i don't know where to start. could anyone help me out? how do i make this variable?

Comment: Why does cycle day for ID 1 jump from 5 to 1 on day two and why is the cycle length 5 for this woman?  I don't understand the data structure from your description. What information is the variable supposed to reflect?

Comment: in my actual dataset i have 35 datapoints for each ID, and cycle lengths are around 30 days. Just to give you an impression of the type of sequence i am looking to create, I provided a very simplified dataset. So in the simple/short version person 1's cycle length is 5 and the period started on day 2, so day 2 is cycle day 1 for that person, while day 1 was cycle day 5 (the last day of the cycle). So i am looking for a variable that reflects each person's personal cycle day based on cycle length and startmenstr. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I think you should update your original question with this description. I see this is your first question so always keep in mind that nobody understands your problem as well as you do :) 

This leads me to another question: "a variable that reflects each person's personal cycle day based on cycle length and startmentr." It's still not entirely clear to me what this variable is supposed to mean? Wouldn't this just basically a combination of values in each column that you could combine to a single variable? As in: 1st day cycle, first day study, gets 1-1, etc.

Comment: sorry :-) The new variable will show me for each person on what day of their menstrual cycle they were. That information is now missing, I only know how long each personal cycle is and what the start day of their cycle was. So the length of the sequence is different between people and the distribution of numbers different within (because they have different start days). It may be very simple but I just don't know how to do this... Hope you or someone can help with some code. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: But isn't that the cycle length? I thought this tells you exactly what day of the cycle they are.

Comment: Cyclelength is the total length of the cycle (e.g. 30 days, in the example e.g. 5 days). As you can see in the example data, that number repeats for every person (between-person level variable). That does not tell us which of those 30 days is today (within-person level variable).

Comment: I've tried my best but I just can't make sense of your data or what you are trying to do.